# Classic bluetooth implementation iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, external-accessory, ios-bluetooth

My app needs to communicate with an android app via classic bluetooth.

We have implemented bluetooth socket in android application. Now i have to connect to the bluetooth service created by this app using uuid.

I have read various post related to this topic, but couldn't find a solution.

Any help will be appreciated.

Q1) Can we connect to iOS app to bluetooth socket created by an android app ?

I have read about Gamekit but it can be used only for communication between two iOS devices only.Correct me if I am wrong.

Q2) Can i use External Accessory framework ?
NOTE:- We are not using BLE in our apps.

Comment: You can only use BLE from an app unless you are communicating with an MFi accessory (which your Android device is not)

Comment: Agreed with Paulw11. This isn't solvable. Apple doesn't give you any access to classic without MFi, and even w/ MFi it's pretty limited (though probably good enough for this if you could get MFi on the other side). You'll need to redesign.

Comment: There is no way an iOS app can communicate with android device using classic bluetooth ? I just need to send and read data just like ble service.

Comment: You've got it. "There is no way an iOS app can communicate with android device using classic bluetooth." You can absolutely do this with BLE; it's not very hard (other than the fact that Android BLE support can be a bit dicey). But not Classic (BR).

Comment: ok, Thanks for help